# How can i get the dropped image x and y coordinates?

Tags: java, android, view, motionevent

I have an image OnTouchListener i want to know the x and y coordinates of image dropped and can i get the coordinates in points? Please help!!

```
 imageView.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListener());
private View.OnTouchListener onTouchListener() {
        return (view, event) -> {
            final int x = (int) event.getRawX();
            final int y = (int) event.getRawY();
            switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)
                            view.getLayoutParams();
                    xDelta = x - lParams.leftMargin;
                    yDelta = y - lParams.topMargin;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:              
                     break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view
                            .getLayoutParams();
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = x - xDelta;
                    layoutParams.topMargin = y - yDelta;
                    layoutParams.rightMargin = 0;
                    layoutParams.bottomMargin = 0;
                    view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                    break;
            }
            mainLayout.invalidate();
            return true;
        };
    }
```